# Plotting specific column of GIS data using geopandas

Tags: gis, geopandas

I am trying to recreate a map of NY state geographical data using geopandas, and the available data found here: https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1325/#NY. I can print the map but can not figure out how to make use of the other files to plot their columns.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Here's a quick setup you can use to download the Shapefiles from the site and have access to a GeoDataFrame:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from io import BytesIO
import requests as r

# Link to file
shp_link = 'https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1325/data/NYgeol_dd.zip'

# Downloading the fie into memory
my_req = r.get(shp_link)

# Creating a file stream for GeoPandas
my_zip = BytesIO(my_req.content)

# Loading the data into a GeoDataFrame
my_geodata = gpd.read_file(my_zip)

# Printing all of the column names
for this_col in my_geodata.columns:
    print(this_col)
```

Now you can access the multiple columns in `my_geodata` the data using square brackets. For example, if I want to access the data stored in the column called "SOURCE", I can just use `my_geodata["SOURCE"]`.

Now it's just a matter of figuring out what exactly you want to do with that data.

Comment: I want to map it just as they did on there website, and zoom into a specific area and maybe highlight a specific type of rock.  I see what you did with the shapefile and I appreciate having that ability now. What I can not figure out is how I can take data found in another file explained in the metadata and found with the same data called nyunits.csv and plot the different ROCKTYPES. Is this possible, I am not seeing how the data fits together, the shape file seems to be only a shape. Thank you.

Comment: So, answering your question is a bit tricky, It is easy to copy data from one dataframe into another. You can do this using either just a simple `merge` or Geopandas' `sjoin`. Here's a quick example: ```x = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['a','b','c']})
y = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3,3,1,1,2,2]})
y.merge(x, on='col1', how='left')```
The problem with your case is finding exactly how these multiple files are connected. You'll have to go through their documentation (at the top of the page) to figure that out yourself, trying to understand what columns are used as identifiers.

Comment: Seems like the data is specifically set up for ArcMap software, I will follow this tutorial to try and map using geopandas: https://towardsdatascience.com/walkthrough-mapping-gis-data-in-python-92c77cd2b87a